# Get html content with data attributes

Tags: jquery

i need send html content from page, but more elements has set data attribute with jquery. How i obtain whole html content with data attributes in html format?

For example, i have div element with class inn, then i set `$("div.inn").data({ hello: "text" }).html("body")`

if i get parent element `$("div.inn").parent().html()` then i receive this
`<div class="inn">body</div>`

But i would like receive this `<div data-hello="text" class="inn">body</div>`

this is only small example, i need this for large code, then i need simple method like .html()

thanks

Comment: You won't get it, since you are using jQuery data api the changes you does will not get reflected in the markup

Comment: try the use `.attr()` instead of `.data()` if you want the updated markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.inn").attr("data-hello", "text").html("body");
```

Comment: Yes, this is solution, but is better solution? More elegant?

Comment: If you want to set an attribute called "data-hello", this is the fastest method.